# Add extra info to Android ImageView in GridView so it can be identified

Tags: android, android-activity, gridview, imageview

I have a GridView where the items are ImageViews (inside a LinearLayout). The adapter that creates the item gets a parameter position, which specifies which item in the list of items that is now being created. How can I pass that information on to the ImageView so when it get's click it will know which image it is?

The adapter creating the items look like this.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_ticket_image_view, null, true);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(position));
    imageView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this.context);

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to  achieve with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method setTag of view to pass information and getTag to get information in Listener.